# Recover vector $x$ from rank-$1$ matrix $Q=xx^H$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, rank-1-matrices

Let the matrix $Q \in\mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ be known. It is also known that $Q=xx^H$, where $x=[x_1,\ldots,x_n]^T$ and $x^H$ is its conjugate transpose. What is $x$? How to recover it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $Q=xx^H$, then $Qx=xx^Hx$. Set $\lambda=x^Hx$; this means $x$ is an eigenvector of $Q$ relative to $\lambda$ (the unique non zero eigenvalue).

On the other hand, if $Q$ is explicitly given, then since it has rank one, you just take a nonzero column $y$ and consider that $x=\mu y$ for some $\mu$. Then do $Q=xx^H=|\mu|^2yy^H$ and you can determine $\mu$ (up to a complex number of modulo $1$). (Assuming $x\ne0$, of course, or the problem is trivial).

Comment: The easier way to find $\lambda$ is from the equation $Q^2=\lambda Q$. Then $(Q-\lambda I)x=0$.

Comment: And then I guess solve for $\mathrm{x}$ from $(Q-\lambda I)x=0$.

Comment: @index That's right.

Answer (score 2):

Given a rank-$1$ Hermitian matrix $\mathrm Q \in \mathbb C^{n \times n}$, we would like to determine $\mathrm x \in \mathbb C^n$ such that $$\mathrm x \mathrm x^* = \mathrm Q$$

Since $\mathrm Q$ is rank-$1$, only one of its $n$ eigenvalues is nonzero. Let $\lambda$ be this eigenvalue. Hence,

$$\mbox{tr} (\mathrm Q) = \lambda + 0 + \cdots + 0 = \lambda$$

Solving the linear system

$$\left( \mathrm Q - \mbox{tr} (\mathrm Q) \, \mathrm I_n \right) \mathrm v = 0_n$$

we can obtain a normalized **eigenvector** $\mathrm v \in \mathbb C^n$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda = \mbox{tr} (\mathrm Q)$. Thus, Hermitian matrix $\mathrm Q$ has the eigendecomposition

$$\mathrm Q = \mbox{tr} (\mathrm Q) \, \mathrm v \mathrm v^* = \left( \sqrt{\mbox{tr} (\mathrm Q)} \, \mathrm v \right) \left( \sqrt{\mbox{tr} (\mathrm Q)} \, \mathrm v \right)^*$$

Hence,

$$\mathrm x := \sqrt{\mbox{tr} (\mathrm Q)} \, \mathrm v$$

---

[linear-algebra](/questions/tagged/linear-algebra) [matrices](/questions/tagged/matrices) [hermitian-matrices](/questions/tagged/hermitian-matrices) [rank-1-matrices](/questions/tagged/rank-1-matrices) [eigenvalues-eigenvectors](/questions/tagged/eigenvalues-eigenvectors)

Comment: Recall that Hermitian, rank-$1$ matrices are positive semidefinite. Hence, the trace is nonnegative.